# Which type of fruit is this

Tags: fruits

I need to identify this fruit. 
Country - India. Found it growing in the wild. Tastes sweet[image: Round blackish berries]
[image: The tree on which it grows]

Comment: It seems that nobody recognize the fruits. So for next spring: could you put also a picture of flowers?  BTW you should NEVER eat fruits that you doesn't know. Many fruits are toxic, poisons, some also deadly toxic.